# How to join two tables using mysql

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, right-join

It's been so long since I did any Mysql queries I forgot how to do basic joins. I have two tables:

Orders_ and 
Members

I need to create one view which displays all the orders with the associated Email and Member_Id.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdaQ7.png <-- Tables

Comment: Do some research first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer to the [MySQL reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

```
SELECT * 
    FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN Members
        ON Orders.coordinateList_Id = Members.Members_Member
```

Answer (score 2):

The query, based on your image, should look like so:

```
SELECT Orders.*, Members.* 
    FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN Members ON Orders.coordinateList_Id = Members.Members_Member`
```